# Can I insert into multiple related tables in a single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have two related tables something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test.items 
(
    id INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(max),
    price NUMERIC(6,2)
);

CREATE TABLE test.books 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES test.items(id),
    title VARCHAR(max),
    author VARCHAR(max)
);
```

Is it possible to insert into both tables using a single SQL statement?

In PostgreSQL, I can use something like this:

```sql
--  PostgreSQL:
WITH item AS (INSERT INTO test.items(type,price) VALUES('book',12.5) RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO test.books(id,title) SELECT id,'Good Omens' FROM item;
```

but apparently SQL Server limits CTEs to `SELECT` statements, so that won’t work.

In principle, I could use the `OUTPUT` clause this way:

```sql
--  SQL Server:
INSERT INTO test.items(type, price)
OUTPUT inserted.id, 'Good Omens' INTO test.books(id,title)
VALUES ('book', 12.5);
```

*but* this doesn’t work if there’s a foreign key involved, as above.

I know about using variables and procedures, but I wondered whether there is a simple single-statement approach.

Comment: No, there is not. You'll have to output to a table variable. Disappointing, but there it is. Note that you cannot place an `INSERT...OUTPUT` inside another `INSERT`, in case you haven't tried that yest

Answer (score 1):

You can using dynamic sql as follows. Although its awkward to construct query like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.items (
    id INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(max),
    price NUMERIC(6,2)
);


CREATE TABLE dbo.books (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES dbo.items(id),
    title VARCHAR(max),
    author VARCHAR(max)
);

insert into dbo.books(id,title)
exec ('insert into dbo.items(type,price) output inserted.id,''Good Omen'' VALUES(''book'',12.5)')
```